How to persist/save and read a ValueObject in the database using NHibernate?
I am using (Fluent)NHibernate and ValueObject of CSharpFunctionalExtensions. I have defined the following ValueObject for my domain logic. However, I have a problem trying to persist it in the database with NHibernate (C#):
public class Keycode : ValueObject
{
    public Keycode(string inputCode)
    {
        if (inputCode.Length != 8)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(inputCode),
                inputCode,
                "Code must have a length of 8 characters,"
            );

        YearDigits = inputCode.Substring(0, 2);
        RandomCodePart = inputCode.Substring(1, 6);
    }

    public string YearDigits { get; }

    public string RandomCodePart { get; }

    protected override IEnumerable<IComparable> GetEqualityComponents() =>
        new[] { ToString() };

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{YearDigits}{RandomCodePart}";
}

It is used as usual in an ORM-mapped class:
public class SomeTable
{
    public virtual Keycode? Keycode { get; set; }

    // ....
}

Error:
FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.


 ---> NHibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: ***, ***, Version=0.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, for columns: NHibernate.Mapping.Column(Keycode)
   at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.get_Type()
   at NHibernate.Mapping.SimpleValue.IsValid(IMapping mapping)
   at NHibernate.Mapping.PersistentClass.Validate(IMapping mapping)
   at NHibernate.Mapping.RootClass.Validate(IMapping mapping)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.ValidateEntities()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.Validate()
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at ***.NHibernateRepository.NHibernateSessionFactory.CreateAndRegisterSessionFactoryThreadSafe(IList`1 mappingTypes, DbSettings settings, String sessionFactoryKey)
   at ***.NHibernateRepository.NHibernateSessionFactory.CreateOrLoadCachedSessionFactory(IList`1 mappingTypes, DbSettings settings)
   at ***.CreateSession() 

Mapping defined as:
Map(x => x.Keycode).Column(nameof(SomeTable.Keycode));

I just want it to persist it as a string, i.e. call .ToString().
I already saw if you use EFCore you can persist ObjectValue's like this and  there is this Stackoverflow question, but both do not really help.
Also I found out an Entity type has been added to the project by @vkhorikov, but this is no entity (or at least I have not thought of it as one). As a ValueType, I don't want it to behave differently when being used as an entity vs domain model.
That means I have a mapping from entity tom (View)Model, which causes issues here.
Trying to change the mapping
I tried telling NHibernate to map it as a string, which sounds reasonable:
Map(x => x.Keycode).Column(nameof(SomeTable.Keycode)).CustomType<string>();

This apparently works for saving the object in the database, but when reading it, NHibernate cannot cast it from string to Keycode, as it apparently does not pass it in into the constructor:
NHibernate.PropertyAccessException: Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches); setter of ****.SomeTable
 ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type '***.Keycode'.
   at (Object , Object[] , SetterCallback )
   at NHibernate.Bytecode.Lightweight.AccessOptimizer.SetPropertyValues(Object target, Object[] values)
   at NHibernate.Tuple.Entity.PocoEntityTuplizer.SetPropertyValuesWithOptimizer(Object entity, Object[] values)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   ...


Cross-posted to CSharpFunctionalExtensions repository
